# PyInstaller giving me a syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

**UPDATE:**  Actually, now I have checked, and PyInstaller is saying Invalid Syntax for EVERY script I have, even ones that I have previously packaged with PyInstaller without any issues. I uninstalled and reinstalled PyInstaller, but it's still having the same problem. Is PyInstaller not compatible with Python 3.5.1? That's the only thing I can think of that I might have updated between now and when everything was working fine

**Original Question:**  I'm sure there is a really simple and stupid answer for what I'm doing wrong, because I can't seem to find any other cases of people having this problem.

I have a script I want to package into a standalone executable.  In the past, I have used PyInstaller with minimal hassle.  Py2exe and cx_freeze have never worked for me.  I'm using Python version 3.5.1 and PyInstaller version 3.2, which I believe is the current version since I just uninstalled and reinstalled.

The command I am trying to use is so simple I feel like an idiot for having trouble.

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py

      File "<stdin>", line 1
        pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py


      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's giving a generic `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` even though that is the exact command straight from the PyInstaller docs.

To be sure, I also tried to include the entire path to my script in the command, added and took out quotation marks, and tried every variation I could think of but it gives me the same syntax error every time.

I'm pretty much a beginner, so any really advanced fixes will go over my head.  But like I said, I assume it's something silly I've missed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any more information about the error? Like a full traceback, or any other output.

Comment: I edited my original question to give the exact output.  it's literally just a syntax error, no other information that I know of.

Comment: Actually, that helped. See my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by your command itself, not by the code it calls.

This part is very indicative:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

You actually tried to run that command in a Python shell.

But it is not Python code. You should run it in a usual shell (cli.exe, bash, …)

Comment: WOW I'M AN IDIOT.  Lol!  I guess it shows that I'm a beginner and I haven't been doing this in months.  Suuuuuuuuper embarrassing.  Thank you so much, haha!  No wonder no one else was having problems that I could find...

Answer (score 1):

## Run It In CMD

Why are you running it in python shell? It's a problem with python syntax because it is not even defined.

```
>>> pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

And, by the way. You are not even importing the PyInstaller module.
Run this line on your CMD:

```
pyinstaller --onefile filename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your script doesn't has any syntax errors. If it's so, then pyinstaller will rethrow the exception and this could be one of the reason.

Comment: My script doesn't throw any syntax errors, it appears to run just how I want it to.  That's interesting, though, I didn't know that PyInstaller would do that.

Comment: Actually, now I have checked, and PyInstaller is saying Invalid Syntax for EVERY script I have, even ones that I have previously packaged with PyInstaller without any issues.  I uninstalled and reinstalled PyInstaller, but it's still having the same problem.  Is PyInstaller not compatible with Python 3.5.1?  That's the only thing I can think of that I might have updated between now and when everything was working fine.