# Pyinstaller Import Error and Syntax Error when passing a .py having modules to .exe

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, pyinstaller, importerror

I'm trying to pass my .py code to .exe but I cant, more simple code (with no calling modules) I can

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame()
name = input(" Enter your Name  ")
print(" Your name is ", name)
```

I opened anaconda prompt and put:

```
pyinstaller --onefile untitled2.py
```

Then I'm getting:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last)
```

and

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The full debug is:

```
(base) C:\Users\INTELIGENCIA\Desktop\Demandas>pyinstaller --onefile untitled2.py
3414 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.1
3414 INFO: Python: 3.10.9 (conda)
3414 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
3414 INFO: wrote C:\Users\INTELIGENCIA\Desktop\Demandas\untitled2.spec
3430 INFO: UPX is not available.
3430 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\Desktop\\Demandas']
4816 INFO: checking Analysis
4832 INFO: Building because C:\Users\INTELIGENCIA\Desktop\Demandas\untitled2.py changed
4832 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
4832 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
4848 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
4848 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
11610 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
11610 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib'
13438 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
13656 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
13688 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\python.exe
13922 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\INTELIGENCIA\Desktop\Demandas\untitled2.py
17271 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
17271 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
30151 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
54562 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
91899 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
105829 INFO: Processing module hooks...
105829 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
105829 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
105844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
105844 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
106469 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
109708 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
111474 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
112900 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
112900 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
112931 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-llvmlite.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
112931 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
112931 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113353 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113368 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113415 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numba.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113446 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113556 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113571 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platformdirs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
113571 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-py.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
114033 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
114033 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
116877 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
117143 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
117408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tables.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
117408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
118361 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\INTELIGENCIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
118956 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
119065 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
119112 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119300 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119300 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119300 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119315 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119410 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119426 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119426 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119457 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
119457 INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
119913 INFO: Trying determine the default backend as first importable candidate from the list: ['Qt5Agg', 'Gtk3Agg', 'TkAgg', 'WxAgg']
120564 INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['Qt5Agg']
120752 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
121179 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
121195 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
121210 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
121210 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
122634 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
122634 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
124717 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
124733 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125092 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125092 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125123 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
125139 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
127840 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
127840 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
127855 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
127855 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
130621 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
130917 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
131089 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
131386 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132042 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132523 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132695 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132710 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132710 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132710 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132851 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132851 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132851 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
132851 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
134964 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shelve.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
134964 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 27, in <module>
    from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\environment\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.events import EventManager
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\events.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.inspect import safe_getattr
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 18, in <module>
    from sphinx.pycode.ast import ast  # for py36-37
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sphinx\pycode\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from zipfile import ZipFile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
140299 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\INTELIGENCIA\Desktop\Demandas\untitled2.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 487, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 620, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 31, in <module>
    dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
  File "<string>", line 0

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried [PyInstaller giving me a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287464/pyinstaller-giving-me-a-syntax-error) by stop using anaconda prompt but my windows power shell doesnt reconize any pyinstaller:

```
C:\Users\INTELIGENCIA>pyinstaller
pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

Additional information:

I got a job few days ago so I installed anaconda on my regarding pc in the company when I try call a recently installed (by pip install) module I get python going it as the module didnt exist so I find the dir of any basic module (module which I have access by anaconda env) and I set the dir at pip install so the module is called with no more error I dont know if my trouble here has anything to do with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyInstaller and Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas)

Comment: Run pyinstaller inside of a virtual environment

Comment: I'm struggling with this problem using selenium but I sumarize it with pandas as it seems all package I call I get this error when I'm trying to pass it as .exe

Comment: I'll add some aditional info I think it will be quite useful

Comment: @DaviAmerico  Make sure you use the @ symbol when trying to comment back to someone.  If you are using anaconda then you shouldn't be using pip.   you should be using a virtual environment. like i already mentioned

Comment: so since I'm running it in "pure" python (pip) I'm not getting the packages from anaconda so would I supposed to use anac env? @Alexander

Comment: That probably depends on which python interpreter you are using.  If you are using the one that is in the AppData directory then use pip, if you are using the interpreter that is in ProgramData/anaconda3  then use conda @DaviAmerico  you can find out which one you are using with `where python` whichever one pops up first is the one you are using

Comment: I use to mess up my dir conf in python and reinstall anaconda @Alexander

Comment: I'm using pycharm for now and got this problem solved, pyinstaller creates a .exe in about 20 seconds when before it was 20minutes and it would not run fine at all. I think using pyinstaller in anaconda env is not worth